# Redirect from ASP to a Wordpress PHP site Using .htaccess

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having trouble trying to redirect an old .asp site to a Wordpress PHP site using .htaccess.

Trying to redirect to:
http://www.example.com

What it's actually redirecting to:
http://www.example.com/Site/2068963711/default.asp

I've done hundreds of standard redirects, but it seems like asp is screwing things up.

What I have:

```
# BEGIN redirect
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/examplesite\.com\/" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END redirect
```

I even added the following:

Redirect 301 /Site/2068963711/default.asp http://example.com/

No luck. Other people have asked, but I haven't seen any real good answers.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are you running an ASP site on Apache? Didn't know that was even possible. Surely the redirect rule needs to go on the server where the ASP site is hosted (IIS?), and redirect the user to the WordPress site?

Comment: We built a new site for a client. Their old site uses .asp. The new one does not. Now I need to redirect all the old indexed files to the new Wordpress site, run on PHP. I have pretty much no knowledge of ASP, so I'm kind of in the dark about it.

Comment: well if you want to redirect from an old site, you need to do it from wherever that old site is running, because that's where the users' requests are going to. You can't do it from the target site, because the user doesn't know about the target site yet, they aren't visiting it. So you need to go to where the old site is hosted and put the redirect rules into _that_ server. You don't need to know anything about ASP (or ASP.NET, whichever it is) in order to do that, but you might need to know about IIS redirect rules as opposed to apache ones, if it's an IIS server.

Comment: We are using the same domain as the last one. Should that go away once the rights change over to us?

Comment: if the DNS is being changed to switch to the new hosting on Apache then probably yes. Requests to the old URL will simply go to your new site if that's what the domain is mapped to.